# Python How to compare similar file names in multiple directory?

Tags: python

There are multiple files in multiple directories. Next, I want to compare the files of similar names from different directories to merge it at later stage. For example: I want to merge a.csv together, b.csv together, etc. from both the directories. I am able to get the file names from both directories but unable to merge of similar name files. The code so far as below;

```
files_dir_1 has a.csv, b.csv, c.csv
files_dir_2 has a.csv, b.csv, c.csv

path = [files_dir_1, files_dir_1]
for i in path:
    for files in os.listdir(i):
        file_name = files[:files.find('.')]
        file_name = file_name+'.csv'
        print(file_name)
```

Comment: By "merge", do you mean concatenate the contents of the files together and save it to an output directory?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a list of the file names, you can use set intersection to get the common file names.

assuming dir1 is a list of values ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv' ...]
and dir2 is the list of values ['file2.csv' ...]

you can do

```
set(dir1).intersection(set(dir2))
```

So in general set operations look like the following:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,4]
set(x).intersection(set(y))
```

to get the list of files names that are in common.

Comment: 'intersection' is not working

Comment: I've updated my answer with another snippet. What does that snippet give you?

What does that block of code give you?

Comment: Its giving the list of strings seperated by comma. Intersection wont work with directories

Answer (score 0):

## Finding CSV file paths

```
import glob
import os.path as path

files_dir_1 = "C:\\tmp1"
files_dir_2 = "C:\\tmp2"

def process_csv_files():
    for file_name in glob.glob("*.csv", root_dir=files_dir_1):
        path1 = path.join(files_dir_1, file_name)
        path2 = path.join(files_dir_2, file_name)
        if path.exists(path2):
            merge_csv_files(path1, path2)

def merge_csv_files(file1, file2):
    # read in files
    # merge data
    # output merged data to disk
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_csv_files()
```

### Alternative to root_dir

```
import os
os.chdir(files_dir_1)
glob.glob("*.csv")
```

## Merging CSV Data

You could use pandas to do the join.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(...)
df2 = pd.read_csv(...)
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="key")
```

Comment: My post is not about merge. Please read the post.

Comment: @AKS I added a section on finding the proper paths to the CSV files.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What is root_dir ? glob() takes one positional arguement but  has given. Please check it again

Comment: @AKS "If root_dir is not None, it should be a path-like object specifying the root directory for searching. It has the same effect on glob() as changing the current directory before calling it. If pathname is relative, the result will contain paths relative to root_dir" https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_dir'

Comment: your code is not working. Have you tested in your local drive ?

Comment: @AKS the paths were incorrect due to escape characters. That has been fixed.

Comment: none of your resolutions are working here. Please check it in your local drive and rectify the answer based on the post mentioned.

Comment: @AKS I tested it by replacing `pass`  with a print statement. It worked for me.